# How to cite an article from the workshop of a conference in BibLaTeX (engineering)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In the bibliography of my electrical engineering PhD thesis, I have some entries for articles which were presented orally in the workshop of a conference (but not in the main conference track). I would like to cite both the name of the workshop, and the name of the main conference. I'm using BibLaTeX and `classicthesis`. So far, I used `@InProceedings` entries with the following fields (example):

```
@InProceedings{citation_key,
    title = article_title,
    author = list_of_authors,
    booktitle = name_of_main_conference,
    series = name_of_workshop,
    year = the_year,
}
```

In particular, I wonder if I'm using the `booktitle` and `series` fields correctly according to the "convention", if there is one.

EDIT: for example, I have defined the following.

```
@InProceedings{smith:2016:eclws,
    author = {Smith, John},
    booktitle = {European Conference on Life},
    series = {Workshop on the Meaning of 42},
    title = {{Great Article}},
    year = {2016}
}
```

which is typeset as follows, using BibLaTeX `style=ieee`:

[12]    J. Smith,  “Great Article”, in European Conference on Life,  ser.  Workshop on the Meaning of 42, 2016.

I don't particularly like the **ser.** part, hence my original question.

Comment: You could use `booksubtitle` instead of `series`. Or `maintitle` and `booktitle`, it depends on what output you prefer and how 'European Conference on Life' relates to 'Workshop on the Meaning of 42'. Of course this still is an abuse of `@inproceedings` if the article was not actually published. Is there any way people can get hold of the article? (For example online.) An answer also depends on what kind of reference list you prepare. For a CV you would probably want the conference listed. For a normal bibliography it would be enough to just give enough info to locate the source.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, people can get hold of the article by googling the title and downloading the freely-available pdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Technically, `@inproceedings` is only the correct entry type if the article did in fact appear in the official conference proceedings. You can of course still (ab)use it.

```
@inproceedings{smith:2016:eclws,
  author    = {Smith, Jane},
  title     = {{Great Article}},
  year      = {2016},
  maintitle = {European Conference on Life},
  booktitle = {Workshop on the Meaning of 42},
}
```

You could use `booktitle` and `maintitle` to format the conference and workshop information as shown above, or `booktitle` and `booksubtitle` as shown below

```
  booktitle    = {European Conference on Life},
  booksubtitle = {Workshop on the Meaning of 42},
```

I prefer the `maintitle`/`booktitle` approach, but that is probably a matter of taste.

---

If the conference name and workshop make it not significantly easier to find the article and you don't have to include them for other reasons (you might want to show them in a CV, grant application, ...), you could also drop the info and only show what is really important to locate the article. If it has a URL,

```
@online{smith:2016:eclws,
  author    = {Smith, Jane},
  title     = {{Great Article}},
  year      = {2016},
  url       = {http://example.ed/~smith/great2006},
  urldate   = {2017-07-08},
}
```

might well be enough.

Comment: Thanks again. I went with the `maintitle/booktitle` approach - which, in the case of `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`, produces identical results to the `booktitle/booksubtitle` approach. With certain documentclasses the results differ. At the end of the day, it depends on the order that I want to show in the produced document (order between main conference name and workshop name). I'd like to see a convention on this, but workshops are by nature unofficial/side events, with no proper proceedings...

Comment: It seems like the maintitle is not shown, if using the article class with bibtex styles "unsrt" "plain" or "apalike". "booksubtitle" is also not recognized. Can anyone edit the question to explain how to expose these features?

Comment: @MRule The styles you mention are BibTeX styles, whereas the question (and the answer!) is about `biblatex`. The classical BibTeX styles you mention do not know `maintitle` or `booksubtitle`.

Comment: I see, I see! (and it seems very hard to do this with bibtex).